# How to pass props or state or even parameter to a component in typescript react

Tags: typescript, react-typescript, react-tsx

Super noob here...

So, I have this school project, and things are getting a bit hard...

I'm trying to pass some props from one component to another and I have no idea why it always fail.

So, the idea is that when someone select an option from one component, the user will get redirected to another page with the ID or the number of that selection so some things will be pulled out of the database and rendered on the screen.

the redirect part seems to be the easy part. this is the code:

```
{this.state.selectedCityCode > 0 && (
      <Redirect
        to={{
          pathname: `/deals/${this.state.selectedCityCode}/${this.state.selectedCityName}`,
          state: {
            cityCode: this.state.selectedCityCode,
            cityName: this.state.selectedCityName
          }
        }}
      />
    )}
```

Now, the redirect work as expected, the url get changed and the the new component ger rendered wrong since the ID wasn't passed, or the target component didn't get it.

in the Router component, this is the relevant part of the redirect:

```
<Route exact path="/deals/:cityCode/:cityName" component={AllDeals}></Route>
```

and in the targeted component, this is the relevant part -as far as I believe-:

```
interface AllDealsProps {
          cityCode: number;
          cityName: string;
}
```

and this one:

```
public componentDidMount = async () => {
const response = await axios.get<Deal[]>( http://localhost/destinations/${this.props.cityCode}/all );
this.setState({ deals: response.data }); };
```

I've used:

```
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
```

and tried to do this:

```
  public componentDidMount = async () => {
    const params = useParams();
    const response = await axios.get<Deal[]>(
      `http://localhost:4000/destinations/${this.props.cityCode}/deals`
    );

    this.setState({ deals: response.data });
  };
```

The issue is, "cityCode" and "cityName" will never get picked up and will always be undefined.

I've seen something about using:

```
this.props.location.state.cityCode
```

but it will always say that "Property 'location' does not exist on type 'Readonly & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }>'.ts(2339)"

Comment: Hi Ahmad Dakhlallah.
Were you able to find a waay around this?

Answer (score 0):

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useParams } from 'react-router';

function Sample() {
    const params = useParams();

    // data will hold the value
    const [data, setData] = useState([]);
    const { cityCode, cityName } = params;

    useEffect(() => {
        const response = await axios.get<Deal[]>(
            `http://localhost/destinations/${cityCode}/${cityName}/all`,
        );
        setData([...response.data]);
    },[]);
}

export default Sample();
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.I get this error: 
`Line 8:16:  React Hook "useParams" cannot be called at the top level. React Hooks must be called in a React function component or a custom React Hook function  react-hooks/rules-of-hooks`

Comment: @AhmadDakhlallah, can yo show us how you are calling the useParams() ??

Comment: public componentDidMount = async () => {
    const params = useParams();
    const response = await axios.get<Deal[]>(
      `http://localhost:4000/destinations/${this.props.cityCode}/deals`
    );

    this.setState({ deals: response.data });
  };

Comment: @AhmadDakhlallah, can you update your question and add the whole code for the component ?

Comment: Done. Please check.

Comment: @AhmadDakhlallah you're trying to use hooks in a class component which you can't do.  But you should switch to a function component because class components are sort of "dated" at this point.